# База данных для интернет магазина

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, проектирование

Вопрос по поводу проектировки реляционной базы данных для интернет магазина (допустим [rozetka.ua](http://Reverse%20engineer%20a%20live%20database%20to%20a%20model)). Сразу скажу, что опыт разработки баз данных такой себе. Я спроектировал (наверное громко сказано) следующую структуру. Главная таблица (таблица товаров) откуда я, наверное, буду брать данные.
Товар:

1. `id (pk)`
2. `Название`
3. `Категория (fk)`
4. `Фото`
5. `Описание`
6. `Цена`

Возник вопрос как реализовать характеристики для каждого товара (туда я хочу поместить все остальные сведения о товаре)? Хочется сделать какую-то ссылку на таблицу с этими характеристиками. И как сделать, чтобы для товаров определенной категории, были определенные характеристики?

Comment: @Дмытрык, да, забыл указать. Это будет реляционная БД.

Comment: @Дмытрык, как я уже упоминал, опыт разработки баз данных у меня небольшой. До этого делал только элементарные БД (реляционные). Был бы Вам очень признателен, если бы вы описали приблизительную структуру.

Comment: @Дмытрык, а что тут стыдного? Все мы люди, все мы учимся. То что вы больше учитесь не дает Вам право оскорблять новичков! Или может вы с рождения знали как реализовывать БД подобной сложности? Еще интересно ваше мнение, как это данные зависят от типа товара? Если вы имеете ввиду, что у процессора есть кол. ядер, у телефона диагональ дисплея, а у штор, допустим, тип материала, то вчитайтесь в вопрос. Я именно это и спрашиваю! Как это реализовать.

Comment: Кто удалил мой комментарий  где упоминается слово "стыдно". ? Теперь все подумают, что я действительно оскорбил ТС. Но ведь это не так. Удаляйте тогда его коммент или восстанавливает мой

Comment: @Дмытрык возможно, в комментариях были запрещённые слова, при наличии которых достаточно одной тревоги от любого участника для автоматического удаления (это был не я, если что)

Comment: Там было сказано, "мне было бы стыдно предъявлять общественности такой результат своей предварительной работы".

Comment: Можно добавить новую колонку под названием additional info и хранить доп. информацию о товаре в виде json'a.

Comment: возможно вам подойдет EAV (Entity-Atribute-Value) модель, попробуйте капнуть в эту сторону

Comment: Прежде всего (на мой взгляд) надо отталкиваться от функционала; Именно функционал накладывает ограничения на структуру бд. Проще говоря: определи что с этой бд будут делать, и исходя из этого уже, - проектируй структуру. Например: нужен поиск по Характеристикам, Свойствам, Тегам, Ценам и т.д. Как из интерфейса планируется выполнять этот поиск ? Далее напиши примерные запросы по различным типам поиска; И наконец спроектируй БД исходя из простоты и скорости выполнения запросов

Answer (score 1):

**1. Создайте таблицу-"справочник" свойств товара**

id - уникальный идентификатор

cat_id - к примеру, "34" (допустим, будет указывать на категорию "Планшеты" в таблеце категорий)

name - к примеру, "Разрешиние экрана" (Будет выводиться на странице товара со значением, или в админке как подпись к полю при добавлении или редактировании товара)

field_type - text (т.е. в админке генератор формы на основе этого поля выведет инфу в  )

**2. Создайте таблицу для дополнительных характиристик товара**

id - уникальный идентификатор

good_id (good - товар) - идентификатор товара из основной таблицы товаров

p_id (p - property - свойство, характеристика) - идентификатор свойства из таблицы-"справочника", по которому сможете вывести название

p_value - непосредственное значение характеристики, к примеру 1280х800

.. приблизительно как-то так.